# How can i send id of the currently posted form data through json response in custom wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, json

I've used wp_send_json() to send the currently posted form data but cannot find a way to send the id attached to it which is incremented automatically from the database,, so that i can update the table data on the page without refreshing...

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

From [an example in the Developer Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/):

> To get the id of the inserted object use `$wpdb->insert_id;`
>
> ```
> global $wpdb;
> $table = $wpdb->prefix.'you_table_name';
> $data = array('column1' => 'data one', 'column2' => 123);
> $format = array('%s','%d');
> $wpdb->insert($table,$data,$format);
> $my_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much man.. This is so helpful.

Comment: If this is helpful, you should mark it as the answer. :-)